# phpgraph lib not showing any output

Tags: php, mysql, graph, gd

Im using phpgraph lib to create graphs on my linux server. I tried an example and it worked, but I had provided it with the data.

then I wanted to connect it to mysql database and plot a query, when I run it, nothing happens, I don't see any output on the page or any errors, I don't see any output on the page at all, even if I put wrong credentials to my database e.t.c any inputs?

I have executed the sql statement on sql server and it's working fine.

the version of php the server has is PHP 5.3.3

```
   <?php

include('phpgraphlib.php');
$graph= new PHPGraphLib(550,350); 


$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password')
 or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());


mysql_select_db('databasename' or die('Could not select database');

$dataArray=array();

//get data from database
$sql="my sql statement";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
if ($result) {
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $salesgroup=$row["var1"];
  $count=$row["count"];
  //add to data areray
     $dataArray[$salesgroup]=$count;
 }
}

//configure graph
    $graph->addData($dataArray);
   $graph->setTitle("Sales by Group");
   $graph->setGradient("lime", "green");
  $graph->setBarOutlineColor("black");
  $graph->createGraph();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I was expecting to see errors on the webpage, but didn't see any on CHROME, I hen opened it in IE and saw error 500.

Troubleshooted through the log file.

Turned out the sql statement wasn't suppose to have double quotes e.g instead of

```
where name="john"
```

it's suppose to be

```
where name='john'
```